# How to search unanswered questions with multiple tags?

Tags: support, search

As far as I know, you can search by multiple tags using the search textbox and typing "[tag1] [tag2] ... [tagN]", after that you'd get a bunch of questions with those tags.

My question is, how can I show unanswered questions including those tasks? What I've tried so far is typing "[python] [recursion]" and then pressing the button "unanswered" but the result of questions are not including the beforementioned tags, what am I missing here?

Example of what I mean here:

[image]

You can see how the recursion tag is not on any of those unanswered questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions with no answers and multiple tags, you could use `[tag] [tag] [tag] answers:0` as search term. In the [new-nav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-nav) you could use `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag%20tag?filter=need-answers&mode=all`, which shows any question with tag, which has no accepted or positive scored answer.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible also to sort out the result of that query by date?

Comment: @BPL the sort button at the right has active/newest/hot/votes/most linked as sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to search for:

```
[python] [recursion] answers:0
```

to show unanswered questions including the tags [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursion). You can obviously exchange and/or add more tags to your search as well.